# ValueError: Too Many Values to Unpack Aptana Studio 3

Tags: python, aptana

I am working on exercise 13 from learnpythonthehardway.org. I should run this code:

```
from sys import argv
script, first, second, third = argv

print "The script is called:", script
print "Your first variable is:", first
print "Your second variable is:", second
print "Your third variable is:", third
```

Then enter "python ex13.py first 2nd 3rd" on command line and should output:

```
The script is called: ex13.py
Your first variable is: first
Your second variable is: 2nd
Your third variable is: 3rd
```

However, I am using Aptana Studio 3 on Vista and I get the 
"ValueError: too many values to unpack" error.

I am new to Python and Aptana so how can I enter the separate arguments here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `len(argv)` might be greater than 4:

```
>>> w,x,y,z=[1,2,3,4,5]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Try printing `argv` to see what `argv` actually contains.

Comment: you could do `script,first,second,third = argv[:4]`   but i suspect there is some other problem perhaps a filepath with a space

Comment: No. I am having trouble entering those arguments. In the exercise, we should enter ex13.py first 2nd 3rd on the terminal but since Aptana doesn't have a terminal, how can I adjust this code should I can enter my arguments?

Comment: what's the value of first,2nd and 3rd?

Comment: @GTyler use `raw_input()`, to get values from user input.

Comment: `first=raw_input('enter the value of first')` 
`second`=`raw_input('enter the value of second')` ans so on..

Comment: read more about [raw_input](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input)

Answer (score 0):

in the script window, right click, ShowIn > Terminal. It will open a terminal window in Aptana. Then type, python 'your script'.py
That will run in way you want I think; Rather with the visual you want.