# detect tooth diminsion in an image using python

Tags: python, image, dimensions

I have a tooth picture, i need to get its dimensions, length and width.
here is the code i tried

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import numpy
import pylab
from PIL import Image
from tr1 import f
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

## open tooth picture

```
img = Image.open(open('kr1.jpg'))
data = np.asarray( img, dtype="int32" )
# find all the 'black' shapes in the image
lower = np.array([3, 3, 3])
upper = np.array([15, 15, 15])
shapeMask = cv2.inRange(data, lower, upper)
```

## find the contours in the mask

```
(cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(shapeMask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print "I found %d black shapes" % (len(cnts))
cv2.imshow("Mask", shapeMask)
```

i get an error

```
[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack][1]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575870/valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack-aptana-studio-3

Answer (score 0):

[`cv2.findContours()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) returns a tuple with 3 values but you are only unpacking 2.

If you only care for the first value it has to be

```
cnts, _, _ = cv2.findContours(shapeMask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```